# Winterizing new wet-treated pressure treated pine deck

Tags: deck, sealing, stain, pressure-treated, weather-resistant

We’re in a townhome and replaced our small 2nd floor deck/porch with wet-treated pressure treated pine 3-4 weeks ago. We had to do it well in advance of the other units for safety reasons. There’s a ton of conflicting info about how to protect the wet type of pressure treated pine.

Important Factors:

- We’re in the Chicago area. Winter is coming.
- Porch will be fully exposed to the elements (rain, snow), including direct sun for the first half of the day.
- Top of floor and railing has been protected with heavy trash bags to protect from the brunt of the weather but bottom half remains exposed.
- Don’t want to do anything too fancy because of the HOA.

Some say not to do anything this type of pressure treated pine for 6 months to avoid sealing in moisture. I’d rather not have a deck covered in trash bags for another 6-8 months, but don’t want to leave it exposed to the elements.

What should I do?

Comment: https://www.deckstainhelp.com/staining-a-new-deck/. This site gives good advice on the subject of when how what product etc...

Comment: Thank you for that. I’m  bookmarking this right now.

Answer (score 4):

Leave it exposed to the elements. You're not doing it any favors by sealing it with plastic. In fact, you'll run the risk of staining it by trapping moisture and/or fostering mildew and other grossness. It's better to let it dry out gradually over the winter and have it seasoned and ready for sealing in the spring.

It may fade or gray out slightly, but the product you apply should bring it back to beautiful with no problems.

Comment: *"You're not doing it any favors by sealing it with plastic."* Understatement of the century. Do what they do at the lumberyard with pressure-treated material - which is generally leave it right out in the weather. That's where it was before it became your deck, and it won't be bothered a bit by a few more months of that.

Comment: Advice taken. Thank you for giving the reasons in your answers. You not only saved me from myself, you saved me several hours of work.